# Error: "code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value" publishing raw transaction in hex format

Tags: transactions, goerli

Hey guys sorry to bother, I'm trying to make an eip1559 transaction in raw format of hex
I'm making the transaction list as described:

```
transactionObjectList=[chainID=5(goerli),nonce,maxPriorityFeePerGas=1gwei,maxFeePerGas=baseFee+maxPriorityFeePerGas=37gwei,gasLimit=21000,toAddress=0x42cAB71dc20BdC5ffeab2112F721eE0Bf55e72E1,amount=0.001,data=0,accessList=[],v=y_parity={0,1},r=....,s=....]
```

The problem might be of the list but I have double checked it from multiple documentations.
I take the keccak256 of list mentioned without v r s values. After I get the `r`,`s` from Dersignature then check if `s>q/2` if true `s=q-s` then try to gnerate public key of signer with v r s to check if the sign is correct.
if true i get the raw transaction by rlp encoding the list and appent it to 0x02.
an example:

```
0x02f8730581af843b9aca0085089d5f32008252089442cab71dc20bdc5ffeab2112f721ee0bf55e72e187038d7ea4c6800080c001a0616f2908bb66363918dfce129d0047186252bde9fe20ce1e7183e7ed8384920fa051f4edadcd77f0ae07feef3ee69432b714ed22b659bbd51cc27baff07767f32b
```

but whenever I publish this to Goerli etherscan i get the error code of:

```
code":-32000,"message":"insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

my address has 1.3 testnet ethereumm and values of transaction are mentionedin the list.
what do I do wrong.
thanks in advance for your kind helps.